# Action listener return value is not getting updated into input text value

Tags: jsf

i called a method from action listener which returns string and i am planning to update it in inputtext field, when i am trying to this i am not getting value into input field

i tried using process ="@this" which perfectly excecute action and do not update the field if i remove that even action is not performing

//here is my backing bean

```
public String getNameWithFormID(long id) {
        TMapper tMapper = new TDao();
         map= new HashMap<>();
            List<TBean> tList = tMapper.getDistinctTName();

            for(TBean t1:tList) {
                map.put(t1.getID(), t1.getName());
            }
        System.out.println("id is"+id+"this is map in submit"+map);
        System.out.println("this is value of id"+map.get(id));
        return  map.get(id);
    }
```

// this is my jsf code

```
                   <p:commandButton  id = "formidid" value="ADD DATA TO FORM NAME" style="margin-right:20px;"  
                            styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process = "@form"  ajax = "true"
                             onclick ="hideshowAddCat();" actionListener ="#{tServices.getNameWithID(tBean.ID)}" update = ":formid:panelgridid" >


                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-4" style="background:#f2f2f2;margin-top:15px;">                              
            <div class="card card-w-title">
            <label for="Nameid">FORM_NAME<i class="fa fa-asterisk" style="color: red;"></i></label>
                <p:panelGrid id = "panelgridid" columns="1" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">
                     <p:inputText id="Nameid" placeholder="FORM_NAME" value="#{tBean.formName}" required = "true">
                     </p:inputText>
                     output is <h:outputText value = "#{tBean.Name}"/>
                </p:panelGrid>    
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSF ajax update means whatever ID/IDs are mentioned in update, we need to re render those components. It's does not means assigning those values. If you want that value to get bind with inputText, assign the value to backing bean variable which is bind with inputText. So after that when you call pass that inputText component to get updated, it will show latest values. Update your backing bean method as

```
public void getNameWithFormID(long id) {

        TMapper tMapper = new TDao();
         map= new HashMap<>();
            List<TBean> tList = tMapper.getDistinctTName();

            for(TBean t1:tList) {
                map.put(t1.getID(), t1.getName());
            }
        System.out.println("id is"+id+"this is map in submit"+map);
        System.out.println("this is value of id"+map.get(id));
        this.formName = map.get(id); // Change is here (assuming that formName is class level variable, as directly bind to backing bean.
    }
```

Comment: Great, I think you can accept and upvote the answer than. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: getting this response